# can someone describe difference between U2 spyplane (glider-like) WING and F-16 Delta Wing

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm trying to learn induce drag and parasite drag and LIFT and load factor for glider. if f16 is loaded with fuel is it difficult to control at slow speed. we know rectangular wing is best slow speed wing. and i know the delta wing is for fast speed and a glider never needs that much speed.

a fully loaded f16 would have very high amount of parasite drag ? how much induced drag when it flies, compared to tapered wing ?

Comment: There's far too much here for one question.

Comment: i only wanted a simple basic answer about drag. the u2 rectangular/tapered wing could stay aloft without an engine; but delta wing requires massive amounts of power and has very small aspect ratio. i wanted just a few comments about  their drag amounts to understand the two types of drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a horribly complex business which I will try to horribly simplify for you.

The biggest difference between these two planes is one is subsonic and the other can be either sub- or supersonic. That means that the design principles for them are completely different, and once optimized, their wing designs come out being totally different.

This makes it practically impossible to make valid performance comparisons between these two classes of designs.